# Почему не работает метод при запуске другого метода?

Tags: python

Начал изучать python на примере telegtam bot написал вот такой код

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
    def send_welcome(message):
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Я Bot')
        bot.get_updates

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

handler - это поступающее сообщения при запросах от пользователя. Сейчас вылавливаются команды `commands=['help', 'start']` и на них от бота следует ответ. Последняя строчка заставляет код работать постоянно.

Как только я добавляю функцию, которая постоянно пингует компьютер

```
def ping_Test():
    while True:
         response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", "192.168.0.32"]).wait()
         if response != 0:
             bot.send_message('667252555', 'Выключен')
         time.sleep(5)

ping_Test()
```

Возникает проблема, функция работает отлично , то есть она высылает пользаку бота сообщения, но бот перестает реагировать на команды, то есть ввожу \start и приветственное сообщение не приходит.

Как только убираю функцию, так все работает. Как заставить бота, продолжать параллельно работать?
Где я не прав?

Comment: Боту некогда общаться с сервером, так как ping_Test() не возвращает управление, навсегда застревая в вечном цикле.  Помогут либо потоки, либо асинхронность.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему асинхронностью

```
from telebot.util import async


    @bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
@async()
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Я FenixITbot, работаю в Фениксе.')
    bot.get_updates


@async()
def ping_Test():
    while True:
         response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", "192.168.0.32"]).wait()
         if response == 0:
               bot.send_message('66725218', 'Включен')
         time.sleep(5)

ping_Test()
```